# How do I have a two way communication in sensor node using tinyOS?

Tags: tinyos, nesc

Sending a packet over the radio is acheived by using AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, msg, len). In receive.receive I can check from which node did I get the message. But how do I send the message back to the same node from which I received message. I have the node ID, how can I get the network address of the one from which I received data and send back to it. Not just only acknowledging the packet. I need to send data once I receive it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of [`AMSend.send`](https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/blob/master/tos/interfaces/AMSend.nc) is:

```
command error_t send(am_addr_t addr, message_t* msg, uint8_t len);
```

where `addr` is documented as *address to which to send the packet*. `AM_BROADCAST_ADDR` is a constant denoting broadcast address: packets sent to that address are received by all nodes in radio range. Once you received a packet and obtained sender's id (by [`AMPacket.source`](https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/blob/master/tos/interfaces/AMPacket.nc)), provide is as `addr` to `AMSend.send`. It has the same type `am_addr_t` which is basically an integer (8- or 16-bit).

Note that an id is typically assigned during compilation or programming a node (see [this presentation](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ochipara/classes/wsn/lectures/tinyos-tutorial.pdf), slide 61) and usually all nodes have by default the same id unless you assign one explicitly.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong in this snippet. Is this what you meant by?
   `uses{
    interface AMSend;
    interface SplitControl as AMControl;
    interface Packet;
        interface AMPacket;
 }`


`Receive.receive(msg_t* msg, void *payload, uint8_t len) {`
    `msg_t* data = (msg_t*)payload;
    am_addr_t addr = call AMPacket.source(msg);
    send_message(addr);
    //rest of the code 
    }
   void send_message(addr){
        //send msg to source now using AMSend.send()
}`